# how to open another file from within vim as a different user (sudoedit | vim )

Tags: unix, vim, sudo

so I've recently learned about sudoedit and how I can edit a file more safely than the standard "sudo vim".

the problem is now, when I'm in vim and "vsplit" or "tabnew" I open it as my user account (no root privileges)

Comment: The `sudo` in `sudoedit filename` only works for `filename`; the whole point of `sudoedit` being to allow you to edit protected files from your regular account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you just want a option to save file as sudo.

You can find mapings for write file as sudo or use tpope enuch plugin.

You will get :SudoWrite and :SudoEdit commands and couple more.

[vim-enuch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch)

Comment: pretty much what I needed, thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

`sudoedit` launches a separate instance of Vim, because it has to manage the lifecycle of the editing session; i.e. write back the edited temporary file with root priviledges. It cannot achieve that from a running Vim session.

However, there are plugins that achieve `sudoedit`-like functionality, for example the aptly named [SudoEdit](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2709).

Comment: [Eunuch](http://vimawesome.com/plugin/eunuch-vim) is another good plugin for this

Comment: The SudoEdit plugin should allow to use `:vsp sudo:///filename`. (I don't use this functionality and just kept it for backwards compatibility)